# How do I remove a SimpleAccount.sol ERC-4337 smart Contract from metamask wallet

Tags: erc-4337

looks like I was duped into signing up to this smart contract by an influencer, should of known better....used remix.ethereum.org and lost a few decent holdings across various chains, ARB, AVAX, MATIC. is there anyway I camn remove this or overwrite it. I know my own fault I do have some things staked in this account which I hope to move to another safe wallet but want to understanmd how either revoke or overwrite this before using it for anything. I have no coding experience can anybody help please.
I can see lots of articles on setting up account abstraction but very little on updating or removing.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.